# Como fazer simulador de lucro através de cliques num link

Tags: php, html, mysql

Olá! Eu estou a fazer um projeto web e necessitava de um simulador de cliques, em que por cada clique no link simulasse dar 1 centimo, 0,01 euros (moeda portuguesa)

As instruções que me deram foram:

vamos desenvovler o módulo de financiamento da aplicação. é o que nos vai gerir os proveitos do negócio.

o ficheiro vai chamar-se navegador.php e tem como função:
. receber os argumentos do patrocinador/notícia e do utilizador (idutilizador - variável de sessão, idartigo, titulo, valor campanha, endereço a abrir)
. escrever na tabela 'proveitos' os campos: idutilizador, idartigo, titulo noticia, valor camapanha, endereço
. informar o utilizador de que está a ser redireccionado para o URL pretendido
. abrir o URL da noticia/patrocinador/notícia

areareserv.php

```
 <div class="col-md-12 fadeIn animated">
            <?php
                include('configdb.php');
                #session_start();
                if  (isset($_SESSION['loginOK'])):
                    if  ($_SESSION['loginOK']==1):
                        echo ("Bem-vindo, ". $_SESSION['nome']);
                        echo "<br><br>";
                        echo ("\n O seu login foi efectuado com sucesso.");
                          if    ($_SESSION['admin']==1): echo " <p><a href='./backoffice'>És administrador. Acesso ao backoffice.</a></p>"; endif;

                            $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM artigos WHERE activo = 1 ORDER BY idartigos DESC");
                                    while($row_artigos = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
                                    {                       
                                echo "<br><br>";
                                echo "<strong>$row_artigos[1]</strong>";
                                echo "<br>";
                                echo($row_artigos[2]);
                                echo "<br>";
                   #LINK ONDE NECESSITO DE FAZER CONTAGEM    
                                echo("<a target='_blank' href='http://".$row_artigos[3]."'>".$row_artigos[3]."</a>");       

                                echo "<br><br>";
                                echo("<hr>");
                                    }

                    else:
                        echo ("Login necessário. Registe-se ou faça login, sff.<br>");
                        header("refresh:3;url=index.html");
                    endif;
                else:
                    echo ("Login necessário. Registe-se ou faça login, sff.<br>");
                    header("refresh:3;url=entrar.php");
                endif;

            ?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: explica melhor o que seria **"clicar no link"** e **"simular dar um centimo"**

Comment: ao clicar no link seria redirecionado para a pagina "navegador.php" executava a query de contar o clique e adicionar 0,01 euros na base de dados no campo "valor campanha" por cada clique.

Comment: simples, no arquivo navegador.php, coloca a lógica de "contar o clique" e a lógica de adicionar o 0,01 euros no banco. toda vez que a página for acessada, a lógica vai ser executada. Tá faltando informações na sua pergunta.

Comment: o problema é eu não saber como fazer essa lógica......@HenriqueSantiago  e nem consigo começar a fazer o código porque não sei por onde pegar

Comment: o que tem de comum nas tabelas artigos e proveitos? ou seja tem colunas com valores iguais e unicos?

Comment: Deram me estas instruções:  o ficheiro vai chamar-se navegador.php e tem como função:
. receber os argumentos do patrocinador/notícia e do utilizador (idutilizador - variável de sessão, idartigo, titulo, valor campanha, endereço a abrir)
. escrever na tabela 'proveitos' os campos: idutilizador, idartigo, titulo noticia, valor camapanha, endereço
. informar o utilizador de que está a ser redireccionado para o URL pretendido
. abrir o URL da noticia/patrocinador/notícia

Comment: vamos lá, essa coluna idartigos da tabela artigos tem os mesmos valores da coluna idartigos da tabela proveitos? Estão relacionados?

Comment: vou meter a print da tabela artigos também na pergunta

Comment: Esse $row_artigos[3] traz o valor de qual coluna da tabela artigos? Eu nunca trabalhei dessa forma, sempre trabalhei com os nomes das colunas.

Comment: trás o valor "link"

Comment: e o centimo seria acumulado na coluna valor campanha da tabela proveitos?

Comment: sim, na tabela proveitos é suposto aparecer o nome/id do user que clicou no link, o id do artigo onde está o link , o nome do artigo onde está o link e o valor que acumulou nesse clique

Comment: echo("<a target='_blank' href='http://".$row_artigos[3]."?id=".$row_artigos[idartigos]."'>".$row_artigos[3]."</a>");  Dai na pagina que vai abrir quando clicar no link recupere o valor da variável 'id' passada no URL e faça update (somando + 0,01) na coluna que acumula os centimos onde idartigos é igual ao valor da variavel id